# Custom ACL Implementation

Tags: java, design, security

I have been trying to figure out an ACL solution for my application which should manage API endpoint's access rights dynamically. Some said that I have an option of Spring Security ACL. I checked it but lack of documentation frightened me a bit. So that I started to design my own ACL implementation; since I did not start implementation can not provide code example but at least I can provide the flow and components planned to be used.

1. A security configuration service. Which will interact with required services to provide dao services between application and database (ofc this will have ref to DAO class as well)
2. A new annotation to be used with aspect to tag/label all endpoints and to catch through aspect.
3. An aspect service to intercept requests and check authorization.

So this a highly overall idea above definitions with their required helpers.

I will trigger aspect per end point access request. Since I know the label for the endpoint (written in the annotation) I can simply cross-check the access rule and user's roles ( I will access it through the Authentication object of Spring).

Any suggestion or a flaw I am missing here ?

Comment: Most security and access control frameworks provide the basics, and then let you define how you want to use them. Can you explain why re-inventing the services provided by, for instance, Spring Security ACL, gains you anything?

Comment: Well tbh, I read a bit and found too much to go with than my requirements. And ofc the lack of documentation and resources lead me to there.

Answer (score 0):

Following the searches, I have convinced to use the way of SpEL with `@Preauthorize`. Let me show it with an example (this is something looks like stackoverflow but for those who somehow hit to this page)

the page I used is [github issues page's comments](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2251)

for authorization component;

```
@Component
public class Authz {
public boolean hasReadAccess(MyUser myUser, Object object) {
    // ...
   return result;
  }
  public boolean hasWriteAccess(MyUser myUser, Object object) {
    // ...
   return result;
  }
}
```

And then use it for your methods like;

```
@PreAuthorize("@authz.hasReadAccess(principal, <method_name>)")
```

*here the `principal` parameter filled by spring security itself*

Comment: Annotating every method would get old fast. I prefer to write access rules using route patterns.

Comment: well that depends on the requirement, at some point trying to manage the route conflicts would cause issues too.